# Cron Job error “Could not open input file”

Tags: php, shell

Seek help for my problem

1. This is my crontab scheduler

```
00 18 * * * /app/apache-2.4.38/htdocs/livechat/mlc_web/autoclose.sh`
```

autoclose.sh file owner is 777

2. This is my 'autoclose.sh' file

```
current_time=$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S") 
php cron.php -s site_admin -c cron/workflow > /var/log/livechat_log/$current_time.log
```

cron.php file owner is 777

However, if i schedule via crontab, I'll get below error msg :-

```
Could not open input file: cron.php
```

If I execute direct (eg. # ./autoclose.sh), I'll get the correct output :-

```
Starting chat/workflow
Closed chats - time out > 0 active chats 43
Purged chats - 0
Ended chat/workflow
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The cron.php should be an absolute path.

Comment: I chg it to **php /app/apache-2.4.38/htdocs/livechat/mlc_web/cron.php -s site_admin -c cron/workflow > /var/log/livechat_log/$current_time.log** but receive other errors

Comment: Error is **Warning: include(var/autoloads/lhextension_autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/apache-2.4.38/htdocs/livechat/mlc_web/lib/autoloads/lhcore_autoload.php on line 272
Warning: include(var/external/Offensivewords/en.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/apache-2.4.38/htdocs/livechat/mlc_web/lib/autoloads/lhcore_autoload.php on line 274
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /app/apache-2.4.38/htdocs/livechat/mlc_web/ezcomponents/Base/src/base.php on line 323**

Comment: What puzzle me is why via crontab failed but success if execute the script direct